# Possible to apply all changed files from 2 commits?

Tags: git

I have 2 commits (A and B) and I want to revert back my code to commit A, but I want to apply all changed files from commit B to commit A.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible; but there are one or two caveats.

If you've published commit A or B to a shared repository, doing this will cause problems for the other users.  If you have other commits "downstream" of A or B, there is extra work to do to bring everything in line.  Because of the way git stores information, modifying a commit in either of those conditions is inherently disruptive.

But if neither of those is the case, it's rather simple to do with `git rebase`.  Something like

```
git rebase --interactive A^
```

This will bring up an editor with the rebase "to-do" list, and instructions on how to edit the to-do list.  You'll change the instruction for B from pick to either squash or fix-up.

Comment: @mallaudin - I already clearly stated that in the second paragraph of the answer; the MAJORITY of the answer text is dedicated to calling out that point.  Also, if you understand WHY it's a bad idea, then you also understand that no other solution to the presented problem is any better.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to reset to commit before commit A and commit again. Remember, you need a soft reset here.

Say you have this hierarchy of commits

```
         HEAD
          |
N -> A -> B
```

- Move HEAD to point N. `git reset --soft HEAD~2`
- It will put all changes in commits A and B to your index, run `git status`
- Create a new commit that will have changes of both A and B commit.

If you have pushed your work to remote repo, you may need to `force push` in order to push changes to remote.

> Remember: pushing changes forcefully to remote will override your work
>   in remote repo. Be careful.

Comment: Resetting public branches to remove commits is a bad idea.

Comment: Haha. Yey! At least I have quoted that text.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset HEAD^^                 // reset to front HEAD contain A and B's source
git add .                        // add A and B's source to new commit
git commit -m "A message"        // commit A and B's source and add commit message
```

Comment: While these commands may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how they answer the question. Please [include an explanation for your commands](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For command-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: @ScottWeldon Finally some sanity from a reviewer!  I may copy your comment to use myself when reviewing.

Comment: @Ajean Thanks! :P Feel free to do so!

Comment: @ScottWeldon Thankyou so much, I will do like this after today. Thankyou so much for helping spicify my error.

Answer (score 0):

First find out the files modified in a particular commit(for reference) this way:

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only COMMIT_ID
```

To revert back any specific commit id just use:

```
git revert COMMIT_ID
```

Comment: By reverting he will loose all the changes in new commit. He just wants to put those changes in previous commit.